# How to convert make proper React Link from source html code?

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have `React` `TypeScript` application (`ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0` Server side).

Users can write html messages and post them on site.
On server side I sanitize and repair posted html to render on client side.

But if there is local links like `<a href="/user/5">link</a>`, targeted my React navigation components, if user clicks this link, whole site is refreshed(rerendered), but I need to act as React Link just to handle link inside React, not to rerender whole site.

How can I convert `A` link to `React Link` (on server and/or on client)?

May be there is something like `PrepairLink` function on client?

Comment: It just sounds like you're "doing it wrong" really. Why would the user submitted html  contain internal links? Are you using "dangerouslySetInnerHtml" to put the user html on the page?

Comment: This is forum, and user can post links to other threads or site pages. Yes html content rendered on view using "dangerouslySetInnerHtml".